# i want to implement sip protocol on microcontroller i.e. using embedded c ,but i want to parse sip packets using perl or tcl

Tags: perl, tcl, sip, microcontroller

a typical sip packet looks like this

```
 INVITE sip:bob@biloxi.com SIP/2.0
      Via: SIP/2.0/UDP pc33.atlanta.com;branch=z9hG4bK776asdhds
      Max-Forwards: 70
      To: Bob <sip:bob@biloxi.com>
      From: Alice <sip:alice@atlanta.com>;tag=1928301774
      Call-ID: a84b4c76e66710@pc33.atlanta.com
      CSeq: 314159 INVITE
      Contact: <sip:alice@pc33.atlanta.com>
      Content-Type: application/sdp
      Content-Length: 142
```

so is it possible to embedd perl or tcl parser in c

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: The only correct answer to this is “Yes”. It's not a _useful_ answer though.

Comment: if its yes than atleast give me a link so that i can study how to integrate tcl or perl with C

Answer (score 0):

I would use a packet sniffer in C. Then identify SIP protocol based on data, push it somewhere  and parse it with Perl/TCL from there. Example:
http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c, or you can build packet sniffer from Perl/TCL itself, very easy task just some considerations when handling TCP/UDP fragmentation